# Is a^n, where n>1000 a regular language?

Tags: computer-science, regular-language

As in the topic, if I have a language with alphabet {a}, does a^n, where n > 1000 a regular language? I am confused. I tried to apply the Pumping Lemma here, and I am unsure of the result. From one side I can see that if I pump out from a^1001 one of a's, then I will have a^1000 which does not belong to L. On the other side I couldn't find any examples of such cases, so maybe my reasoning is wrong.

Comment: this question is not clear.  You may want to use http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's regular. Consider the regular expression `a{1001}a*` where `a{1001}` is a string of 1001 `a`'s.

Comment: Thanks. What about (aa)*. Is this also regular? I can pump it for string i.e. aaaa  with i = 1 and I will get aaaaa which does not belong language. Am I right here?

Comment: `(aa)*` is clearly regular, you just described it with a regular expression. The equivalent 3-state FSM is not hard to find.

Comment: Ok, clearly I have to read more about reg. languages and pumping lemma . Thanks again :)